# How to automate pdf printing (including renaming&save as) in iMacros?

Tags: pdf, printing, imacros

Using iMacros, I go to several websites with a search box (e.g. Google) and fill in these boxes with variables 'A','B' from a .csv file and search. Next, I would like to print the page that shows using a virtual pdf-printer (to get a pdf file). However, I can't get the pdf-printer to automatically rename the file (in a specific format, i.e. 'A' 'B' website.pdf) and save it to a specific location.

Current Code:

```
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Batchtest.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT CONTENT={{!COL1}}<SP>{{!COL2}}
WAIT SECONDS=2
ONPRINT P=
WAIT SECONDS=1
PRINT
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

How would I tackle this problem? The ONDOWNLOAD command and similar commands don not seem to work - does the pdf-printing process take place *outside* the browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ‘iMacros’ is not supposed to save some info in PDF format, unless it is a download. See [wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS).

Comment: Right, thanks for that quick reply. So if I would really want to do the auto-rename/saving process of the printer, would it be possibly to - for example - run a script in javascript (or whatever is doable, I have no programming expertise) which calls on my imacro and subsequently calls on a pdf printer?

Comment: Suppose that probably it could be realized with ‘iMacros Browser’ and some scripting language (not JavaScript). I’m working only with ‘iMacros’ for Firefox where there are no printing commands. However I definitely know that the latter may be used to rename files automatically and to place them in a specific location.